# Compactness implies Continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity, compactness

I am stuck on this question (probably there are many counterexamples, but I can't find any).

"Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ that preserves compactness (i.e, for every $K \subseteq R$, then $f(K)$ is compact). Is $f$ continuous?"

thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the inverse direction is indeed true:
the image of a compact set $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ under a continuous function $f$ is compact (iow $f(K)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is compact). $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational, otherwise $f(x)=0.$ So $f(K)$ is either one or two points.

Comment: I don't think there's anything less continuous then that :-)

Comment: f(0) = 0 and f(x) = 1 for all other x..

Comment: @Dror: There are plenty. This function, while not continuous, is the pointwise limit of continuous functions. One can find functions which are not even Borel measurable. That means that they are far far less continuous than this one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes, but would a person usually think of those if sober?

Comment: Will, of course. It's when you're drunk you start flirting with the idea that every function is Borel measurable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, don't go to the dark side! Think of the light!

Comment: As long as it's not light beer...

Comment: @AsafKaragila just curious: If restricted to $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is there still something "less" continuous?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, fair enough. If you need help avoiding black magic, or excess viscosity, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656820/divorce-problem-solution-by-astrology-91-9694850756

Comment: Hey @WillJagy, I got it. thank you all for the comments!

Comment: @Dror: I am talking about functions $\Bbb{R\to R}$. There are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ functions which are Borel (which turn out the be the smallest class of functions containing all the continuous functions and closed under pointwise limits), so *most* of the functions are even "less continuous" than that. If you want to be slightly more "specific", pick any non-measurable subset, e.g. a Bernstein set or a Vitali set, and consider its indicator function.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks. I am not familiar with most of what you pointed out, but I'm surely going to dig in, using the information you provided. The possibility of no point-wise limits is surprising to me, and I must know the details :-)

Comment: @Dror: If you are familiar with the inductive definition of Borel sets (i.e. not just "the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the intervals", but the Borel hierarchy) then proving this would be a piece of cake. If you don't, then perhaps it would be wise to familiarize yourself with that first.

Answer (score 4):

Floor function should be another example.
The image of each compact (bounded) set is a finite discrete set and therefore compact.